# AngularJS $digest already in progress at onScroll event

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive as also known from other threads.
Now I was running into an AngularJS apply exception:

> Error: $rootScope:inprog
>   Action Already In Progress
>   $digest already in progress

Does anyone know how I can prevent this exception?
I tried it with a trigger but with no success.

```
 (function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myProject.common')
    .directive('asScrollTop', asScrollTop);

asScrollTop.$inject = ['chatService'];

function asScrollTop(chatService) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { 
            chatMessagesOfUser: '=',
            currentUser: '=',
            messagesPage: '='
            },
        link: link
    };
    return directive;

    ////////////

    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        console.log(element);
        var trigger = false;
        element.on('scroll', function() {

          if(element[0].scrollTop <= 0 && trigger == false) {
              trigger = true;
              var page = scope.messagesPage + 1;

              chatService.getChatMessagesOfUser(scope.currentUser.id, page).success(function(response) {
                  scope.chatMessagesOfUser = response;
                  scope.$apply();
                  trigger = false;
                }).error(function(data) {
                    console.log('error in asScroll.directive.js#link');
                });
          }
        });
      }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

That just means that you don't need to call `scope.$apply();` because a digest is already occurring, so whatever you were trying to achieve with it is already happening. Just remove the line and things should work fine.